# Trying to find if a range of dates apply to a range of dates

Tags: excel, date, range, pivot-table

I am working on Excel to try to create a project effort utilization stacked bar chart. I have start and end dates for each project and effort %. I want to be able to organize these by month and by 'Resource' and have the effort by month.

This is what I want the end result to look like:

[image: This is what I want the end result to look like.]

This is the type of data I have:

[image: This is the type of data I have]

I can not figure out to have excel read the start and end date as a unit. Pivot tables and timelines do not help. I have tried sumif, vlookups, pivot tables but the logic does not seem to work with the start and end dates.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There's a number of different ways to tackle this, some of which are dependent on what version of Excel you have. What version are you running?

Comment: Also, have you considered using a Gantt Chart for this, or to supplement this? The setup will be very similar to what you're trying to achieve. See https://peltiertech.com/excel-gantt-charts/

Comment: @jeffreyweir yes, I tried to use a Gantt chart, but that tells me the length of time in a calendar form and not really the amount of effort per project per month

Comment: @jeffreyweir I am using excel 2016 MSO